# how to call a record in python

Tags: python, odoo-10

In account.invoice model we have a many2one relation with payment.term model:

```
    payment_term_id = fields.Many2one('account.payment.term', 
                                   string='Payment Terms', 
                                   oldname='payment_term',
                                   readonly=True, 
                                   states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]})
```

I want to create a method inside payment.term model that calls the id of account.invoice record in where we entered to the payment term form. How is this possible with python code? I know to do this with xml code we use `context`

```
context="{'default_invoice_id': active_id}"
```

but I need to do this in python code.

Comment: Can you post the `class` definitions  and maybe an example of the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is :

- change the field `payment_term_id` in `account_invoice` model to :

  ```
  payment_term_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='account.payment.term', 
                             string='Payment Terms',
                             inverse_name='invoice_ids', 
                             oldname='payment_term',
                             readonly=True, 
                             states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]})
  ```
- in other model `account.payment.term` add the field :

  class AccountPaymentTerm(models.Model):

  ```
  _name = 'account.payment.term'
  _description = 'Payment term'
  _inherit = 'account.payment.term'

  invoice_ids = fields.Many2one(
      string='invoices',
      comodel_name='account.invoice',
      required=True,
      ondelete='cascade',
  )
  ```